# Int Array[ ] not printing good.

Tags: c++, c, arrays, printf

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
   {
   int indeks, a[11], j, rezultat[50];
   int n = 0;

   printf("Unesite elemenate niza\n");

   while (n < 10)
   {

     for(indeks = 0; indeks < 10; indeks++);
     scanf("%d", &a[indeks]);
     n++;
   } 
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
    printf("%d\n", a[n]);
   }

}
```

Hello , I have problem that this doesn't print array as a integer number that I enter in .

It always print out -858993460 ten times.

this is how it looks in cmd.
(sorry for bad english)

```
 Unesite elemenate niza: 
 1     /input starts here
 3
 5
 1
 0
 2
 3
 5
 7
 4     /ends here
-858993460  
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460 
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460      /output result
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You have a loop within a loop, and a semicolon as the body of the second loop. This means that **all** the data that you enter ends up at the position `10` of the array.

Comment: Remove semicolon after `for(indeks = 0; indeks < 10; indeks++);` **Voting to close as a typo.**

Comment: [main() returns an int](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#main-returns-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop does nothing, since it ends with `;` and as the `while` loop iterates, `indeks` will always be `10`. I suggest the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()                                  // correct function type
    {
    int indeks, a[11], j, rezultat[50];
    int n = 0;

    printf("Unesite elemenate niza\n");

    //while (n < 10)                        // delete while loop
    //{

    for(indeks = 0; indeks < 10; indeks++)  // remove trailing ;
        scanf("%d", &a[indeks]);

    //n++;                                  // delete unnecessary line
    //} 

    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[n]);
    }
   return 0;                                // add return value
}
```

Comment: while we are at it, `j` and `rezultat` are unused, and `indeks` (im assuming he meant index) and `n` can be declared inisde the `for` loops.  `cin` and `cout` would probably be better to use, and you can also remove the `{` and `}` near the second for loop

Comment: @dwcanillas , oh yeah about that j and rezultat ... I used(copied) my old code so i forgot to remove it , sorry :D.

Answer (score 1):

This 
`for(indeks = 0; indeks < 10; indeks++);`
does nothing except incrementing `indeks` 10 times.
I could write the whole code corrected for You but how will You learn then?

Comment: geez man :D , i got answer few seconds ago , no need for writing whole code. I'm new to c++ and whole programing thing . Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have a couple of syntax errors. **Weather Vane** has posted the correct version, please look at his answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    const unsigned int A_SIZE( 10 );
    int a[ A_SIZE ];

    printf( "Unesite elemenate niza\n" );

    for ( unsigned int indeks( 0 ); indeks < A_SIZE; ++indeks )
        scanf( "%d", &a[ indeks ] );

    for ( unsigned int indeks( 0 ); indeks < A_SIZE; ++indeks )
        printf( "%d\n", a[ indeks ] );

    std::cout << "Enter a character to exit: "; char c; std::cin >> c;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did , I looked up for Weather Vane it all works fine . Thanks for answer . I'm sorry , I'm still new to this whole thing.